# SVG.js Plugins in Node / svgdom

Tags: node.js, svg.js

Can anyone tell me how to get SVG.js plugins working in Node. I'm using svgdom like this, which gives me the svg code for a simple rectangle:

```
const window = require('svgdom')
const document = window.document
const {SVG, registerWindow} = require('@svgdotjs/svg.js')

registerWindow(window, document)
const canvas = SVG(document.documentElement)
canvas.rect(100,100).fill('yellow').move(50,50)
console.log(canvas.svg())
```

I want to use svg.path.js. Where do I put the svg.path.js file and how do I require it in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

`svg.path.js` is a community plugin and wasn't updated by its author for version 3 of svg.js. Therefore it is not usuable with svg.js v3 and svgdom yet.

Comment: Oh OK - it is listed on the V3 documentation plugins page but thanks, I'll stick to the built in method for now.

Comment: Sorry for that - I guess it was overseen